# Dimplejs Axis points to years

Tags: dimple.js

I have made a Ghost Bubbles Dimplejs chart as in http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_change_bubbles
My xaxis is years (2010 to 2015) Dimplejs by default specifies it as 2.0k How do i override it?

```
x = chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Year");
x.timePeriod=d3.time.years;
x.overrideMin = 2009;
x.overrideMax = 2016;
```

Should I go for addTimeAxis? 
My data has only years in the format yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

The purest answer would be to change to a time axis but that would involve some additional changes to the logic.  The simple answer to your actual question is to set the tick format before drawing:

```
x.tickFormat = "d";
```